# How to select an item from a dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="buttondropdownperson" name="buttondropdownperson" class="form-control" placeholder="Please select the personyou are here to see" type="text" required="">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          &lt;-
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Duty Officer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Phillip Smith</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jessica Moore</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Roger Nand</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Steve Jobs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Phil Schiller</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Carter Williams</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rebecca Johnson</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the above Boot Strap Form, when I select a person from the dropdown, I don't see the text in the "TextField" where you see it says "Please select the person..."

I am new to Node.JS and jQUERY. How can I get the selected person from the dropdown-menu and display it on the button ?

JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/officaluseonly2015/95h49av5/1/

[image: Example Of My Form]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/officaluseonly2015/95h49av5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can add click event on the `li`or `a` and on click load the value of that element in input box.

Example:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu>li').on('click', function() {
  $('#buttondropdownperson').val($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="buttondropdownperson" name="buttondropdownperson" class="form-control" placeholder="Please select the personyou are here to see" type="text" required="">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        &lt;-
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Duty Officer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">John Doe</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Phillip Smith</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Jessica Moore</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Roger Nand</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Steve Jobs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Phil Schiller</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Carter Williams</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Rebecca Johnson</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add the code in your js in `document.ready()` , updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crot7v9f/1/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am learning alot about  JS. One other question. Do you know why the site looks different in IE vs Chrome? In Chrome, it looks perfect. In IE, the dropdown is missing and looks weird

Comment: Ryt now i don't have ie. I will have access to after 8 hrs. If you would wait i will definetly render vode ie and let you know the reson

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate it

Comment: @softwareisfun :  Dropdown works perfect in ie 11 for me. What version IE are you using and also post URL to your website.

Comment: I was testing locally using IE11 on Win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

This should put the selected list item text in your input box.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").on("click", "a", function() {

   $("#buttondropdownperson").val($(this).text());

});
```

Play [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cygnudg/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need Input with dropdown? If yes try this [plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/?utm_source=jquer.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation) built using bootstrap. There is an option `data-live-search="true"` which will enable search(I believe input added was for search)

Comment: dropdown is a must. Its being deployed on a touch screen monitor with NO keyboard. (A virtual keyboard will be present)

Answer (score 0):

add class .item then:

```
 $('.item').click(function() {
        var value =  $(this).html();
      $("#buttondropdownperson").val(value) 
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kvj742w/1/)